# Can I sail a raft on a European river with commercial traffic?

Tags: safety, rivers, sailing

I'm thinking about sailing a part of the [Danube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danube), alone, on a self-built raft. I have no experience sailing rivers on any serious basis.

I'm considering a raft for a number of reasons:

- It's cheap.
- It provides more space than a boat.
- I can easily take a bicycle.
- It's more easily replaceable in case of theft than a boat (plus, who would want to steal a raft?).
- There are no worries about selling it or transporting it after the journey has completed.

However, the portion of the river that I want to sail is used by commercial freight traffic. My worry is that using a vehicle with little steering and no engine can lead to life-threatening situations with river freight ships, like [this one](http://www.intuitivmedia.de/data/picture/detail/865.jpg), and cruise ships. I imagine getting caught in their suction can be very dangerous.

Has anybody here attempted something similar, or have some river experience?

Are there traffic lanes on European rivers, so it might be possible to do this if you stay close to the bank?

Who would I talk to to find out whether this is a completely idiotic plan, or somehow feasible without risking your life too much?

Naturally, I would sail during daytime only. I can swim of course, and I'm prepared to wear a life vest at all times if so recommended.

Comment: You're going to run into problems finding a place to tie it up, assuming you want to get off occasionally (in addition to all the other problems).

Comment: @victoriah yeah, that is an issue too. Although the river looks relatively friendly and seems to have lots of small branches, and there are many harbours (*if* they accept rafts next to all their yachts, of course. :)

Comment: How do you plan to manouver it into a harbour? Just wondering.

Comment: @victoriah I would have to have *some* way to steer the whole thing, and some way to maneuver it manually for short distances (ie. paddles). That's going to be a different topic, building it

Comment: Well, +1 for being incredibly brave!

Comment: @victoriah thanks! :) Well, if seasoned experts unanimously tell me that I'm likely to get killed by a careless freighter, I won't do it. But I'd really, really like to.

Comment: +1 For trying to live the dream, give us an update when you decided

Comment: @Pekka웃: This is an old question, but I am curious: did you make it in the end? And if yes, how did you handle the customs issue? I mean especially on the Hungarian-Serbian and Serbian-Romanian borders, and also the issue of whether you are on Romanian or Bulgarian, respectively Ukrainian waters.

Comment: @Akabelle I did not end up doing it! I still want to, but things being as they are, it may be a couple years until I can. I had bought a book about sailing the danube (wit a motorized boat) where they talk about how to handle customs, but sadly I sold it a couple months back, else I could have looked up what they recommend.

Comment: @Pekka웃 good luck anyhow, hope you can get to it one day :)

Comment: @Pekka웃 I found this and made me think of your post: http://krikat.de/videos/

Answer (score 27):

*I've never taken an unpowered, hand-built raft out onto a commercial river, but I do have experience under sail and under power on the Columbia River in the United States. What I know about maritime law, tradition and etiquette might not be exactly what they expect in Europe, but I imagine the principles are much the same.*

---

In most cases, a craft without a motor has the right of way. On your raft, you'd be free to use the width of the river channel as you saw fit.

However, large ships with deep drafts, like river cruisers or river barges, are typically confined to a particular lane in the river. Their right to use the lane supersedes your right of way as an unpowered craft. You would have to make way.

If you're passing another vessel on equal terms, say coming head on with a small powerboat, tradition dictates that both you pass each other port-to-port. The left side of your vessel passes the other ship on its left; aim your raft to the right of vessels you're passing head-on.

You might consider posting red and green lights on your port and starboard sides, respectively. For that matter, you might even consider building a mast and flying a flag to increase your visibility. Just don't fly anything with an established meaning, like diver-down, or the NATO alphanumeric flags. Your country of origin, upright, would be enough.

You should talk to cruise ship captains and lock masters on the river for more advice about the Danubue in particular. The Danube has locks, and the lock masters decide if and when a vessel can enter the lock. I have no idea if a lock master would allow a hand-built raft into a lock, but if you're considering it, you should ask in advance.

The cruise ship captains operating on the Danube could give you more practical advice about the nature of the river and your responsibilities on the Danube.

Comment: Great advice!  I don't know about Danube, but from experience I know that on many small rivers in Europe, small hand built raft are usually allowed into locks.  One warning: Danube gets quite large in its lower part, and is supposed to have currents that can be quite dangerous to small water crafts, so be very careful.  Talking to people who know the river is definitely very good advice.

Answer (score 16):

### The good news

Navigating the Danube with a raft is certainly possible, and has been done: for instance, [Flossbusters](http://www.flossbusters.de) are a group of Dresdners who went all the way from Bertoldsheim to the Black Sea on a home-built raft over the course of five summers. Their craft, the good ship *Dresden*, looks quite similar to what you envisage:

[image: the Dresden raft]
Source: [flossbusters.de](http://www.flossbusters.de/de/donau_2006_DE.html)

Googling in German for "Donau Floß" turns up several other tales of successful rafting on the Danube. In particular, [this discussion thread](https://www.outdoorseiten.net/forum/showthread.php/25650-Donau-mit-Flo%C3%9F) has a lot of useful information.

### The bad news

The worrying aspects of your plan are (to me) that you want to travel **alone** and **unpowered**. All the accounts I've come across involve more than one person and some kind of engine. I'd personally regard an engine as *essential* if travelling alone on a raft on the Danube: a single person paddling will have a lot of trouble manoeuvring a raft effectively. Of course this doesn't mean that you have to use the engine for any longer than necessary, but you need the capability. (In addition to being a practical requirement, an engine will be a legal requirement at least on some parts of the Danube.)

### Legal aspects

The Danube passes through 10 countries, so I think the legal aspects are best considered once you've decided which countries you're aiming for. Registering the 1.3-ton Flossbusters raft apparently required submission of CAD drawings, fitting a 10 horsepower engine, and demonstrating provision of fire extinguishers, first-aid box, horn and [various other things](https://www.outdoorseiten.net/forum/showthread.php/25650-Donau-mit-Flo%C3%9F?s=33e50269e5850dd7fc4c1240a172e88d&p=371714&viewfull=1#post371714). In general, the smaller and lighter the craft, the less paperwork there will be.

### A possible alternative

In your place I would give serious consideration to a **canoe** or **kayak** rather than a raft. You'll have to travel a little lighter, but the logistics will be greatly simplified. You might even be able to satisfy your bike requirement if you bring a lightweight folding model. [Canoeing the Continent](http://www.canoeingthecontinent.com/about/) is a very informative account of a canoe trip from the Atlantic to the Black Sea (going along the Danube for the eastern part) and has a lot of information which will probably be useful even if you decide to go by raft.

Comment: You can carry a full size bike and a dolly to tow the canoe with in a canoe.  [How to carry a bicycle in a canoe?](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/6948/how-to-carry-a-bicycle-in-a-canoe)

Answer (score 9):

There are rivers and channels which **forbid sailing without an engine running!** In Europe there are several countries which have by themselves more than one law system. But as every law, they are written in a book. Ask in a boating shop (or tourist information point) for more localized information and *buy* that book of law. In several countries that is a requirement by law.

Indeed stay away from the suction at backs but **also at fronts and be aware that such ships you posted can't see 300, 500 or even 1000 meters ahead by the dead angle they have and can't manoeuvre** quickly. Ships do not have brakes.

"I can swim of course": This doesn't mean anything if you sail. Too much can happen that makes you unable to swim. A life vest is the one that will turn your face up and has a collar on which your head will float if you're unconscious (those ugly ones) and not the swim vests (less ugly) that only give a *feeling of safety*.

Answer (score 1):

You obviously have underestimated the potential for danger, due to self admitted  lack of experience on the water. As a blue water sailor for 50 years I strongly suggest you rent a car or take a cruise line as you will either end up in jail or swimming for your life to avoid being pulled under and chopped into chum by a prop. 
...This come from a federally certified transportation manager as well as a sea captain with a perfect safety record.