# Looking for a 20 to 40mi out and back or loop trail in Maryland

Tags: hiking, united-states

My daughter and I were going to hike the AT through Maryland.  She goes to school there and really wanted to do a muli-day hike.  We recently gave up on the idea b/c the logistics of the end to end travel are both costly and time consuming.  We decided to keep it simple this time and just find a loop or out and back that we can knock out in two long days, maybe three, however I'm having difficulty finding any lengthy trails of the sort.

Comment: How does the AT in Maryland not meet your requirements for an out and back trail?

Comment: I suppose I could pick a random location to hop on, walk 15 miles and turn around. I was just fishing for recommendations. I wanted to see if there were any well known hikes I might have missed.

Comment: There are any number of variations you can make, to turn a long trail into a series of day (or two) trips.  One of [my examples is here](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/7245/4079)

Comment: Does it have to be MD or would trails in PA or VA work?

Comment: @StrongBad the OP's location is in their profile.  That will probably answer your question.

Comment: @JamesJenkins the question says MD specifically, but there are lots of trails that are less than 20 mi over the boarder that might work. They might be on a 50 state mission (or something like that) or maybe nearby things work.

Answer (score 2):

What about [Chesapeake Ohio Canal Trail](https://www.traillink.com/trail/chesapeake--ohio-canal-national-historical-park) near of Washington DC?

Comment: I was actually going to suggest the C&O from DC to Brunswick and then catch the commuter train back to the start.