# How long would it take to canoe the entire length of the Belize River upstream in July?

Tags: rivers, canoes, paddling, river-navigation

Hopefully someone has made this trip so I can craft a realistic scenario for a novel I’m writing.

Assuming you had a crew of one experienced paddler and two inexperienced paddlers, about how long would it take to traverse the entire length of the Belize River upstream in July/August from Belize City to Branch Mouth Park (where the river starts)?

Are there places requiring portaging? Apparently there are [78 runs or rapids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belize_River),  but I believe they are only Class I and II. Possible some are Class III.

How many hours a day could they paddle, assuming all are reasonable fit?

Approximately how many miles a day would they progress?

EDIT:
This would be in the mid-19th century, so the canoes would be birch-on-frame or wood-and-canvas construction. Maybe 17’ long?

It appears during the wet season the flow rate is [15 cubic meters per second](https://www.oas.org/cdmp/document/blzriver/belize.htm).

Comment: I can't answer the question - but based on the river form, it is a lowland river - there are unlikely to be places to portage. How far you could go depends on fitness and how much you are carrying - 1 canoe, >1 canoe? kayaks - what sort?. River flow rates at that time of year?

Comment: @bob1 One canoe, three paddlers. Above-average fitness. Not sure what kind of canoe. This would be mid-19th century, so I’m assuming birch-on-frame or wood-and-canvas. Maybe 15–17’ long?

Comment: hmm, discharge rates I found are average of 155 cumec - low of 10-20: [p16 here](http://www.mbrs.doe.gov.bz/dbdocs/tech/watersheds.pdf). I can't find any data on velocity or average width to estimate this. Looks like ~50 m at mouth, ~20 m further up so 155 cumec will be fairly fast flow. Sticking to sides of river it's possible, but would be hard work

Comment: I'm guessing that's the dry season flow rate because the link you've given shows that wet season floods can top 100x that.

Comment: It is very likely faster to walk than paddle up-stream. I have canoed down many rivers and the couple time we wanted to to back upstream it was very difficult ; unless the river is more like a lake than a river.

Comment: @blacksmith37 This would be in 1867. There would be no roads, so if they don’t take the river it would be about eighty miles through mountainous jungle. I know from historical documents that the Belize River was a major water highway from ancient times up to the 19th century. Just can’t find any specifics of how long the upstream journey took. There’s a downstream race every year that takes four days.

Answer (score 6):

I canoe a bit, almost [exclusively down stream](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/7239/4079) I tend to paddle at a steady speed, with almost no drifting.  I average about 2 miles per hour (3KPH).  As the river is [290 kilometres (180 mi) long](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belize_River) that gives a down stream time of about 90 river hours.  If you did 10 hours a day on the river, you could do the whole thing in 9 days.

BUT going up river, and with no knowledge about water speed, portages, etc It would be really difficult to estimate.  There are a lot of variables.  Some portages can take a day or more.

More people do not make the canoe significantly faster over the course of a long journey.  A canoe can only go so fast, plus the more you put in it, the harder it will be to paddle.

Lewis and Clark have a well documented journey that made good use of canoes.  Some of their work is available on [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/author/6210) it might provide background.