# What are the navigation considerations on the Ohio River between Wheeling WV and Parkersburg WV?

Tags: canoes, biking, kayaks, river-navigation, ohio-river

I want to travel by canoe from Wheeling, West Virginia to Parkersburg, West Virginia on the [Ohio river](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohio_River).

What are the navigation considerations?  Also I will have a bike and trailer for the canoe, will be interested in bike trails paralleling or intersecting the river.

- Locks and Dams
- Camping/accommodations
- Launches
- River side services (away from large cities)

Hypothetically the trip would be completed, with only muscle power, rowing or pedaling.  In either a single trip or by pedaling upstream and rowing down stream, in one or more outings.

Related Question (Upstream) [What are the navigation considerations on the Ohio River between Pittsburgh PA.& Wheeling WV?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/7200)