# Looking for cart for standup paddleboard for 1 mile trip, by foot

Tags: paddle-boards, transportation

I am looking for a device for transporting a 12' inflatable, fins-attached SUP ~1 mile by foot or perhaps by bike.

I hate the idea of inflation/deflation.

I would appreciate whatever insights you have on dollies, carts, bike carts, straps or the like.

Comment: Welcome to the Outdoors Stack. Please take a [tour] and visit the [help] if you need more information about this site and what we do here. Shopping requests are normally not allowed, but I think you are looking for suggestions on methods rather than particular products. If so, can you please edit your question to make this clear and add the dimensions of your SUP and if you need to carry anything else.

Comment: Excellent. I was wondering if a dolly/sack barrow/hand truck or similar might work, though then you would have the full width of the board in front of you.

Comment: As it is, this rambling qustion runs the risk of being closed. If you put some real effort into editing it, giving it some focus, it could be useful. One option is to ask "what are some good options for transporting my SUP?" and then provide a good comprehensive answer based on your research, but provide images, not just links.

Comment: I've edited the text down, to make the question more enticing.  (May or may not add an self-answer.  Don't have it figured out yet and my thoughts are too stream of consciousness.)  May also look for a SUP forum, with more SUPers to answer (question may be an outlier here).

Comment: Some possible relevant ideas: https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/9256/how-to-tow-a-canoe-with-a-bicycle

Comment: That's a great link, thanks.  IF anything, some of the discussion (such as the tow swinging) makes me less likely to get a bike trailer.  Just deflate it if moving several miles.  And use a super simple dolly or even a strap for the 1 mile walk.  Thinking my next move is just buy a strap and see how cumbersome a 1 mile hoof is.

Comment: I don't get the question, don't inflatable SUPs generally come in a bag with some straps that you can just carry or wear like a rucksack? At least all the ones I saw did... Or are you asking to inflate your board first and only then transport it for 1 mile?

Comment: @fgysin in my enthusiasm to simplify the question it lost the "I don't want to keep inflating it".

Comment: @WeatherVane Makes sense, but you should add that to the question I think.

Comment: @bob1 or you could pull it.  Sack trucks pull nicely though the grip isn't great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your board is sturdy but not heavy, wheels under one end and holding onto the other end, or making a grip with some straps, will work for walking.
If your board is not sturdy enough, or what you need to transport is rather heavy, wheels in the middle and a good balance will make it easier.

If you want to cycle with your board you can fix a connector to the board and the other part to your bike, or you can buy a cart with an arm long enough to reach from at least the middle of your board to beyond the end where you connect it to the bike. And like with the walking option, it depends on the board which version will work best.

If the arm of the bike cart comes high enough you can also use it to walk with, giving you two options.

A carry strap to make walking with your board without wheels easier will likely be the cheapest option but it will depend more on your muscles and if you do a good workout on the water, carrying the board home will be a challenge. It might be a fast solution, but I doubt it will be the best in the long run.

Don't worry what other people will think, just see whether you think the road is safe enough to walk and/or cycle.

Comment: Good point about the walk, which will be ~2 miles altogether. The OP sounds cheerful about it but hasn't tried it yet. I wonder what kind of neighbourhood it is. Being on a bicycle will get through it more quickly, and may be easier to handle any heckling from kids.

Comment: Awesome answer.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

- There are specific **carts/dollies** for transporting surf boards and
  SUPs.
- There exist also **strap systems** that attach around the board twice with a shoulder strap to carry the weight.

Find plenty of examples here:
https://www.amazon.com/paddle-board-cart/s?k=paddle+board+cart

(Or google for "surf board cart" or "surf board carry strap").

Example of a cart:
[image]
https://www.blueplanetsurf.com/blue-planet-rolling-surfboard-cart-2021.html

Example of a strap:
[image]
[https://www.amazon.com/PPXIA-Adjustable-Accessories-Paddleboards-Surfboards/dp/B0BZ85N52P/ref=sr_1_46?keywords=paddle+board+cart&qid=1692343721&sr=8-46](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BZ85N52P)

Comment: I would go for straps as well.  Just keep in mind that they could be impractical in high winds that are coming from the sides or back.